# Failure upon migrate init (mybatis-migrate) caused by not finding template_README in the mybatis-migrations.jar

Tags: mybatis, dbmigrate

Just installed mybatis-migrate on my macbook and I haven't been able to run `migrate init` without getting this error:

```
ERROR: Error copying org/apache/ibatis/migration/template_README to {projectDirectory}/./README.  
Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:{path}/mybatis-migrations-3.3.0.jar!/org/apache/ibatis/migration/template_README (No such file)
```

Has anyone encountered this error before? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOsX if you're getting this error try to switch to 3.2. It resolved the error for me.